# Background does not show when content Overflows Horizontally

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm experiencing an issue with overflow content in divs.  I am using SharePoint and some of the content [namely Libraries or Lists or big webparts containing the aforementioned] will extend past the visible display space, but the body content doesn't scroll properly.

My structure looks something like this:

```css
html {100%}
body { background: #010831; font: 500 1em 'Raleway'; height: auto; min-height: 100%; margin:0; overflow:hidden;}
   #container { margin: 0 auto; min-height: 100%; }
   #topBar {background: #010831; font: inherit; padding: 5px; height: 80px; margin-bottom: 1px;}

  .topline {width:100%; height:20px; font-size:0.8em; color:#fff;}
  .social {width: 30%; float:right; text-align: right; font-size: 1.2em;}
#searchBar {width: 25%; float:right;}
#searchBox {border-radius: 10px; width: 250px; background:#343a5d; height:25px; color: #fff; font-size:1.2em;}
#quicklaunch {width:18%; min-height: 35%; color: #666; font: 600 1em 'Raleway'!important; padding-top:4px;}
    #main {width:100%; background:#fff; display:flex;}
#s4-workspace {width:auto!important; overflow:auto!important; background:#fff;}
    #content {width:80%}
    #footer {background:#000; width:100%}
```

```html
        <body>
        <div id="s4-workspace">
          <div id="bodyContainer">
              <div id="container"> 
              <!-- this is the beginning of my custom coding, and my own styles. -->
                    <header id="topnav">
                       TOP NAV MENU HERE
                    </header>
                      <section id="main">
                          <div id="quicklaunch"> SIDE NAV HERE</div>
                             <div id="content"> ALL USER DRIVEN CONTENT GOES HERE</div>
                       </section>
                   <footer id="footer"></footer>
                </div>
               </div>
    </body>
```

What's happening is that the Content div that's set to 80% won't display content that extends past the screen properly.  The content overflows but the background is my body color (dark Blue).  I can't set the content div width to 100%, as that will make the entire div go under the sideNav AND it affects how webparts then display.  [They stretch across the entire screen forever, since by default SP allows the webparts to take up full width of their containing zone].

Essentially, all I want is for the background color of my content div to stretch when the content overflows.

[image]

Comment: "Essentially, all I want is for the background color of my content div to stretch when the content overflows." what do you mean the content overflows? What content? The text you have in there now just wraps when it's > 80%, and the background extends just fine. Does the code in your post fully demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @MichaelCoker      the above code is just a slate... i can't really copy & paste all the code that you'd find in a SharePoint page as there are 2030349343 other classes that the app uses which i have no control over, 100,000 scripts & so on.  the 'all user content here' is not the actual content....   i will post a picture, however, so what i'm talking about specifically is seen.

Comment: you don't have to paste the entire page - can't you just post an element or two or whatever it is that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @MichaelCoker  again, i'm not sure if you're familiar w/ SP, but an "element or two" for content that is generated by ASP is long and extensive... plus the stuff could contain proprietary info..  i can give you the full customized css if you think that might help, however.